# Ionizing a Gas Into Plasma by White Light

Tags: plasma-physics

I am curious about whether I can use different frequencies of photons to ionize a gas into a plasma without high temperatures or high voltage. The different frequencies of photons would excite the electrons to higher and higher energy states until the electrons break away from the EM force from the nucleus. I know that lasers have been used to "cool" atoms down reducing the kinetic energy and was wondering if lasers can be used to "heat" atoms also increasing the kinetic energy of electrons and thus increasing the electric field.

Comment: lasers are used to *heat* a metal surface so thermionic emission of ions and electrons comes out and makes a plasma https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0963-0252/2/3/013

Comment: Is this two separate questions? Lasers of course aren't white.

Comment: For most standard gases, excitation to the first excited state requires photons above the visible spectrum. Multi-photon processes are possible, but you need intense laser pulses to have this process available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and indeed this is exactly how some 3D displays work. See for example [this article from the IEEE Spectrum web site](https://spectrum.ieee.org/femtosecond-lasers-create-3d-midair-plasma-displays-you-can-touch):

> Those brightly glowing voxels (pixels in three dimensional space) are air molecules that have been ionized at the focal point of an infrared laser and are releasing extra energy in the form of bluish-white photons. The plasma doesn’t last long, so the way to make a display is to use a laser that scans through a volume of air very quickly, firing tens or hundreds of of thousands of times per second to create a sequence of short-lived (nanosecond-scale) voxels that create the effect of a moving image.

The ionisation is actually thermal. The laser heats the air and collisions between the superheated air molecules cause ionisation. In principle you could do it by directly ionising molecules in the air, but this would require hard ultra-violet lasers.

Comment: But temperature or thermal energy is only limited to the black body spectrum. Unless I am requiring a very hot temperature, I should only expect most of the heat energy to come from infrared light.